# Shortcut code writing with loop

Tags: sas

I am trying to create a loop that wiil shortcut code writing.
I want that every veriable from x1- x30 will be equal: x square i, when i is the index of x1(i.e 1).

For example x7 will be x7=x**7;

I wrote a code, but it doesn't work. and i don't know how to fix him. I will glad for your help people.

```
DATA maarah (drop = i e);
e = constant("e");
do i = -10 to 10 by 0.01;
x=i;
y=e**x;
output;
end;
length x1-x30 $2001;
do i =1 to 30 by 1;
x i=x**i;
output;
end;
run;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close.  You need to declare an array.  You don't explain what the first half is (the e**i part), so it's not clear what you want here - do you want a few thousand rows with powers of e, and then some rows with x1-x30?  And why do you output each time in the second loop?  To answer the core question, here:

```
DATA maarah (drop = i e);
e = constant("e");
do i = -10 to 10 by 0.01;
x=i;
y=e**x;
output;
end;

*length x1-x30 $2001; *what is this?  Why do you want it 2001 characters, instead of numeric?;
array xs x1-x30; *you would need a $ after this if you truly wanted character;
do i =1 to 30 by 1;
 xs[i]=x**i;
*output; *You probably do not want this.  Output is probably outside of the loop.;
end;
run;
```

I would guess what you really want is this:

```
 DATA maarah (drop = i e);
e = constant("e");
do i = -10 to 10 by 0.01;
 x=i;
 y=e**x;
 *length x1-x30 $2001; *what is this?  Why do you want it 2001 characters, instead of numeric?;
 array xs x1-x30; *you would need a $ after this if you truly wanted character;
 do j =1 to 30;
   xs[j]=x**j;
 end; *the x1-x30 loop;
 output;  
end;  *the outer loop;
run;
```

Comment: It's give me just the first step of the loop (i=-10).

Comment: Had a typo, and realized you should switch the loop counter for the second loop to something else - fixed